# Fatal Error while call method from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controller.
I have one test method in first view controller as follow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       myLabel.hidden = true

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   func showLabel(){
       myLabel.hidden = false
   }

}
```

If i call showLabel from another class it give me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Another viewController is as follow

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   @IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {
       ViewController().showLabel()
   }
}
```

If i call showLabel Method from ViewController the its works fine but if i call it from SecondViewController then i got error.

Comment: `ViewController()` creates a **new** ViewController, which is never shown on screen

Answer (score 0):

Both your view controllers use storyboard/xib; when you create such view controller instance in code (as you do in `Save` function) you need use `UINib` class or `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method of `UIStoryboard` class, since default initializers (like `init()` you used for `ViewController`) know nothing about outlets and storyboard/xib associated files (outlet property `myLabel` will always be nil).

If your code not just template, then you should refactor it, because performing UI changes in view controller that not presented on screen (and never will be) not have sense

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya topic is too broad, thats why I answered only to question in title. I suggest you to read this manual https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

Answer (score 0):

You need use delegate: 
1-Creat a protocol with a function describes with you are planning to do.

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
  func showLabel()
}
```

2-Add a delegate in your `SecondViewController` with the type if the protocol `ViewControllerDelegate`.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate? // add delegate
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.showLabel() // call the method from delegate
  }
}
```

3-Implement the `ViewControllerDelegate` in your `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
```

3-Set the delegate in the first view controller inside `prepareForSegue`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       myLabel.hidden = true

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   func showLabel(){
       myLabel.hidden = false
   }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            viewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Still it giving me same

Answer (score 0):

It's because your label "myLabel" is always nil.
Your label is part of your first ViewController. The label loads when the view loads. Since the ViewController view has not loaded, the label has not loaded either, and therefore will be nil

Comment: what is solution for this?

Comment: your secondviewcontroller is initial viewController?

Comment: No, initial is viewController

Comment: You can use delegate or NSNotification concept for this.

Comment: Is there no any solution with my current scenario?

Answer (score -2):

just add class before function:

```
class Math{

    class func addition(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int{

        var ans: Int = numberOne + numberTwo
        return ans
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from another Swift class like this:

```
Math.addition(40, numberTwo: 2)
```

To assign it to a variable i:

```
let i = Math.addition(40, numberTwo: 2) // -> 42
```

Comment: This should be removed, it doesn't relate to the question at all